# Sound not playing with video on Android device

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I have a mp4 video I'm playing with the VideoDisplay that runs fine on desktop browser (the mp4 was created with Camtasia). When I load it from Google Play on my mobile Nexus 7 it plays the video but does not have the sound. On other Android devices it does play the sound with it. When I debug locally on the Nexus 7 the screen is blank. I just purchased the Nexus 7 so it is the first time seeing this.

Comment: What version of the AIR SDK are you building with? I've had similar issues with 3.1 - 3.3. 3.0 always worked well and I haven't had those issues on 3.4 either, though there is an issue where a video will not ever end a buffer state on 3.4. I ended up having to write a video player for Android and a second video player for iOS. h.264 video in Flex Mobile is an absolute nightmare

Comment: I tried 3.1 and also 3.5. I think I solved it by exporting to mov. It still cuts off the sound at the end on one of the clips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported to Quicktime MOV format and they are playing correctly on the devices I own.